# Demo code from the MVGC Toolbox documentation not working on R2018b

Tags: matlab, runtime-error, libraries, undefined-function

I need help in using the MVGC (Multivariate Granger Causality) Toolbox for MATLAB.

I tried to execute the demo code which is provided [here](https://users.sussex.ac.uk/~lionelb/MVGC/html/mvgc_demo.html), but the code is not executing properly, since many of the functions (e.g `rng_seed()`, `var5_test()`) do not exist in MATLAB.

I searched for those in the MATLAB support but was unable to find any information regarding them.

Comment: In order to improve your question and prevent it from being closed, you should: 1) add a link to the discussed documentation page. 2) Post the code that you were trying to run and the error you're getting (see also: [mcve]). 3) Tell us which function from the toolbox you _actually_ need (I'm assuming it's not the example as-is).

Comment: @Dev-iL Thank you for helping with the question. The code is same as given at the link. The two functions which are mentioned in the question are the function unidentified by Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: it's likely not related to the specific MATLAB version, and you should just include the toolbox in your search path.

The functions aren't identified because they're not part of the MATLAB installation, but are rather included in the toolbox itself (which you should [download manually](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/sackler/mvgc/)). Then, for them to be recognized, download the toolbox, extract it, and add the contents of the toolbox (including subfolders) to your [MATLAB path](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html).

Specifically regarding the functions you mentioned, they're found here:

```
var5_test -> \mvgc_v1.0\demo\var5_test.m
rng_seed -> \mvgc_v1.0\utils\rng_seed.m
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help. I am new to Matlab and was really stuck here. Thank you once again.